# Regex 2 words in the same order in the same line

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search for a match inside a text that contains the words:

```
[IF (anytext) [OF] (anytext).... endofline
```

in a given text, I have tried this pattern without luck:

```
^(\[IF(.*?)\[OF\]).*$
```

It works if the text is only one line, but when I feed in a full text with several lines it doesnt works.

Comment: `^` and `$` are the start and end of the string. If you want start and end of the line, use the `m` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wrong duplicate ;)

Comment: this is not a duplicate

Comment: @JoseG Please add your code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JoseG If adding `s` or `m` or both modifiers does not solve your issue, you must clarify the issue by posting the code you are using and explaining what behavior you get and what behavior you expect.

Comment: OMG you are absolutely right, I dont know why I had the ^ and $ in my code, I removed it and now works. thank you very much!